# How to use firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword on firebase-functions as API with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm building API with Nodejs using firebase-funtions for login with email and password function. But when I use firebase.auth() then recieve error: firebase.auth() is not a function. I searched a long time but don't have result as expect. I have any questions:

```
 1/ Can we use firebase.auth() (it's client-SDK) on firebase-functions ?

 2/ If can't use it. What we should do authenticate email/password from firebase as RESTful API.
Here's my code:



const firebase = require('firebase');

const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

var firebaseConfig = {
  // my config
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

admin.initializeApp({
  // my config
});
```

Comment: Why are you trying to sign in a user using server-side code? Signing in is a function of client code.  You can create a user in server code, but that's a different API.

Comment: Tks for reply. Because my project have mobile app and front-end app so I want to write API to both also can use it.

Answer (score 1):

As I implied in my first comment, you can't sign in a user on the server side of your app.  It's not clear to me why you need to do that.  Each supported mobile and web platform has their own way of signing in the user locally.  They should not be sharing some server code to do that particular task.  There are other things you could delegate to a server, but signing in is not one of them.

The client needs to sign in on its own because it needs to generate a ID token that identifies the user, so that the client can make requests to other Firebase products that will be authorized for that particular user.  This token must come from the client in order to be secure.